# Using activerecord-import to mass import CSV data and update duplicates - Statement Invalid Error (not enough memory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am attempting to mass import about 1.8 million records from a `CSV` using `activerecord-import`.  This is a monthly import that usually updates a few thousand records and adds a few thousand as well, so overall, the majority of them will be duplicates.   A record can be identical (don't want it in the DB), an ID can be identical but a certain date parameter may be different (want to update and keep), or it's a brand new (obviously want it in the DB).  Anyway, this is what my code looks like currently:

```
        arr = []
        converter = lambda { |header| header.downcase }
        Zip::File.open(content) do |zip|
            zip.each do |entry|
                if final === entry.name
                     data = zip.read(entry)
                     CSV.parse(data, headers: true, header_converters: converter, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1') do |row|
                        arr << row.to_h
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        Carrier.import(
            arr,
            on_duplicate_key_update: [:dot_number],
            validate: false
        ) 
    end
```

After attempting to process, here is the error that I am getting:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 970861ms (ActiveRecord: 340014.3ms | Allocations: 598662052)



ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::OutOfMemory: ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 8388608 in memory context "ErrorContext".
):
```

I believe it's probably because I am attempting to update a large majority of the records.  So, I am currently attempting this now:

```
        arr = []
        converter = lambda { |header| header.downcase }
        Zip::File.open(content) do |zip|
            zip.each do |entry|
                if final === entry.name
                     data = zip.read(entry)
                     CSV.parse(data, headers: true, header_converters: converter, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1') do |row|
                        arr << row.to_h
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        Carrier.import(
            arr,
            on_duplicate_key_update: {conflict_target: [:dot_number], columns: [:mcs150_date]}
        )
    end
```

I am new to backend work, so while I am waiting to see if my new solution helps, I was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try to ``import`` each file separatelly in ``zip.each``

Comment: I have to parse the file first, covert to hash and push to arr within the CSV block.  There's only one file anyway - the logic within the ````zip each```` is simply used to prevent the ````README```` from being read/parsed.  Can you maybe show me a code example?